# how to get struct's start address from its member's address

Tags: c, struct, memory-address

In C language, how to get struct's start address from its member's address?

```
struct type1 {
    //...
    int member1;
    //...
};
struct type1 obj1;
```

And `ptr1` is the address of member `member1` in `obj1`, how to define
macro `#define start_add(ptr1, type1, member1)` to get obj1's
start address?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can do this using [`offsetof`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Offsetof):

```
#define start_add(ptr1, type1, member1) ((type1 *)((char *)(ptr1) - offsetof(type1, member1)))
```

Comment: I think that you have an extra `&` before `(ptr1)`. `ptr1` is the address of the member already.

Comment: You should also add an extra set of brackets around the entire macro result - remember that `->` has higher precedence than `(type)`, so if you want to apply `->` to the result you will need them.

Comment: @caf: also a good point, since `->` is frequently what will come next.

Answer (score 1):

this from windows wdk

```
/* 
 #define CONTAINING_RECORD(address, type, field) ((type *)( \
      (PCHAR)(address) - \
      (ULONG_PTR)(&((type *)0)->field)))
*/
```